# C++ LNK1561 while debugging

Tags: c++, debugging

I'm using VS Pro 2015 and I have a small project with Windows Forms.
The project is finished and compiling is not a problem in "Debug" mode. When I'm changing it to release I get the LNK1561 error.

Have you got any idea?

Comment: Are you sure that you have make the same linking configuration in release mode? like linking all libraries?

Comment: The C++ winforms templates were removed from VS a while ago.  So you have to hack it yourself in VS2015, it requires changing several project properties to get it going.  Standard mistake is changing them for the Debug configuration but forgetting to do so for the Release configuration.  Like the Linker > System settings that is the most likely reason for this link error.

Comment: I have checked the everything under Linker, everything is now the same, expect SubSystem. On release I set it to not defined and on debug it's on different options. But I cannot use it on release.

Comment: http://mcn-www.jwu.ac.jp/~yokamoto/openwww/vsg/VCpp2012FormApp/

This is the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Try checking project settings for both debug and release configurations, there should be difference somewhere.